Placing a view on bottom view on another view is not working properly using SwiftUI
I want place a banner(view) bottom of the VStack(which takes screen's width and height) apart from safe area.
The issue is when I am trying to assign a background color, the view is going out of bounds.
Here is code i have written
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Color
                    .gray
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom){
                Text("Your subscription has expired, please renew it")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .border(.white)
                    .background(.red)
            }
        }
    }
    #Preview {
        ContentView()
    }

But when i added .background(Rectangle().fill(.red)). It is working
is there any way it should be done.
Any solution to that

Please post your code as text, not images. The code should also be a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce your problem.

Welcome to SO. Please review [ask].

@Sweeper I hope you understand what my problem is?

Please add a screenshot with the explanation of what exactly doesn't work as you expect. I copied your code to a sample project, and the result looks fine be me: Grey background (with a touch of white above the safe area), and a red banner with the text in the bottom of the screen.

Welcome new user. Now that your question is cleaned up, this is a terrific question. The answer given is great and I learned a lot, thanks!

@lazarevzubov the red banner should not go to the screen, it should be within gray Vstack.

This is because the two ways of applying the background go to different implementations:

.background(.red) uses background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:), which ignores safe area edges by default

.background(Rectangle().fill(.red)) uses background(_:alignment:), which doesn't ignore safe area edges by default (and also happens to be deprecated).


If you don't want the color to ignore the safe area edges then a simpler way to apply it is:
.background { Color.red }

This actually uses background(alignment:content:), which is another implementation again.
